# How to compare two objects excluding a single object property?

Tags: c#

i need to avoid duplication in a list for that i used the below code . I would like to know whether there is any option to compare the objects as (item = findobject) except item.id . i dont want to type the entire property list here. Please suggest a better method.

```
var result =(obj.Find(item => (item== findObject)));
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, reimplement [GetHashCode()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx). But you need some CS knowledge to get it right, it's not trivial.

Or `Equals` for that matter.

Answer (score 3):

Just an option: you could use reflection to get a list of properties, and then compare them bertween objects, something like:

```
public static bool CompareExcept<T>(T first, T second, params string[] excludeNames)
{
  foreach (PropertyInfo pi in typeof(T).GetProperties())
  {
    if (excludeNames.Contains(pi.Name)) // case sensitive
      continue;
    object propFirst = pi.GetGetMethod().Invoke(first, null);
    object propSecond = pi.GetGetMethod().Invoke(second, null);

    if (propFirst == null)
    {
      if (propSecond != null)
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
      if (!propFirst.Equals(propSecond))
        return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

All the usual caveats connected to reflection apply, so this is slow, and it's best avoided in tight loops, but it's relatively easy to use

```
Person p1 = new Person { ID = 1, FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe", Age = 50 };
Person p2 = new Person { ID = 2, FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe", Age = 50 };
Person p3 = new Person { ID = 3, FirstName = "Jane", LastName = "Roe", Age = 50 };
Person p4 = new Person { ID = 4, FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe", Age = 60 };

bool areSame = CompareExcept(p1, p2, "ID"); // True
areSame = CompareExcept(p1, p2, "Age"); // False
areSame = CompareExcept(p1, p3, "ID"); // False
areSame = CompareExcept(p1, p3, "ID", "FirstName", "LastName"); // True
areSame = CompareExcept(p1, p4, "ID"); // False
areSame = CompareExcept(p1, p4, "ID", "Age"); // True
```

If you have lots of types you need compared, this is usefull. However, if this is a one time thing, you're better off explictly comparing all other fields.

Comment: ugh. This is definietely an abuse of reflection. We are working with types known at compile time here, and there is no need for this stuff.

Comment: @Tamas: It's not specifically stated that it's used for just one type, and I explicitly state that this is not a good fit for that scenario. Unless the OP clarifies the question, I think this is a viable answer.

Comment: Fair enough. I'm sorry but I can't revoke my downvote unless the question is edited (SO doesn't let me). Drop a comment here so I see it if that happens.

Comment: @Tamas, np, just some SO idiosyncracy, I can live with a -1 :D

Comment: +1'd because in some situations Equals is too broad. In my case with a validation scenarios: one scenario requires other properties excluded than the other. Besides: these days we have `nameof()` :-)

Answer (score 1):

You may override Equals method and specify list of compared properties explicitly there.

Comment: Do you have an example of how this would be performed?

Answer (score 0):

If you own the type of object to find, I suggest you to overload the Equals operator. So you will write the comparision logic once, and then will simple use "==" to compare them.